# Hidding secret way to access web content

Tags: php, cookies, web-crawler

This is a really odd goal so I hope you will understand what I need.

I want to display some content on my website only to some selected people.
Let's say I have this page : index.php

```
Welcome on my website !
<?php if($hasAccessToSecretContent) echo 'The weather is sunny'; ?>
```

I'm looking for a way to give certain people this access. I really don't mind security issue, the content isn't that secret. I just want most of random people not being able to see it, nor noticing that something is hidden.

For user convenience, I want to stay on index.php, wheter they want to browse the secret content (so I don't want to put all my secret content on index.secret.php and tell them to go there everytime they want to see it)

I first tought to use cookies. I can hide that *hasAccessToSecretContent* boolean in them. I can ask my friends to go to *website.com/give/me/that/secret/cookie* to setup their browser, and once they get their cookie, then can go back to index.php . That way, they don't have to do anything more everytime they want to acces secret content. (Of course, some smart people could get the url, but as I said, I don't mind as long it is only a few)

The main issue with it, is that my friends would need to reopen that url whenever they switch devices, browser or reset their cookies.

Is there another way to have a one time secret authentification ?

I know it is quite a weird question, so don't hesitate to ask more details.

Comment: Surely if you give the cookie a long enough time-out, your friends won't need to keep opening the "give/me" url as long as they don't clear their browser cookies. And you could have your code keep extending the cookie time-out as one of the things it does for those with special access.

Answer (score 0):

Use magic in your URL =)

Like this: `http://localhost/index.php?magic=qWe324rt`

So in your PHP:

```
Welcome on my website !
<?php if($_GET['magic'] == 'qWe324rt') echo 'The weather is sunny'; ?>
```

Pros:

- you can send a link to anyone and he will just need to click on it to see hidden content
- you can bookmark this link
- if you change this magic key in PHP, then all previous uses will not be able to see content anymore, but new ones will do

Cons

- URL is not secure, so theoretically someone can use the same URL to see your data, but you said it is not that critical